# nodejs ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, clob, node-oracledb

I'm trying to insert data in nodejs using oracledb, but im getting "ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column" on a CLOB column. Following is my code

```
let query = `insert into messages (ID, BATCH_MSG_TYPE, MESSAGE, RECIEVED_DATETIME)
                    values (:id, :msgType, :message, :insertionDatee)`;
let binds = [ id, type, message, new Date().toDateString() ];
```

Error is on MESSAGE column which is CLOB. The data in message variable is read from an xml file of length 34886 which is not much for a CLOB.

Ran the same query on sql developer it inserts the data successfully

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version are you using of nodejs and oracledb ??  is it node-oracledb 1.12.1 or lower ??

Comment: Also which versions of Oracle DB and the Oracle client libraries are being used?  I agree with @RobertoHernandez that it sounds like you have an old stack.